# Diophantine equations $x^n-y^n=2016$

Tags: diophantine-equations

> Solve equation 
>   $$x^n-y^n=2016,$$
>   where $x,y,n \in \mathbb N$

**My work so far:**

If $n=1$, then $y=k, x=k+2016, k\in \mathbb N$

If $n=2$, then $2016=2^5\cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$

$x-y=1; x+y=2016$

$x-y=2; x+y=1008$

...

If $n=3$, then $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=2016$

$n\ge4 $. I need help here.

Comment: $x^4-y^4=(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)=(x+y)(x-y)(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: Note that $x-y \mid x^n - y^n$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: I'm sure the OP knows all this, noting the level of his answers and other questions.

Comment: If $n\ge 11$, then\begin{align}x^n-y^n&=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})\\&\ge x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+ xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1}\\&\ge 2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\cdots+1\\&=2^n-1\\&> 2016.\end{align}

Comment: In case $n=1$, both divisors $x\pm y$ must have same parity. So the case $x-y=1$, $x+y=2016$ does not work

Comment: @choco_addicted Simply $2^{11} - 1^{11} =  2047>2016$

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche: No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found the solutions for $n=1$ and your method for $n=2$ works (with Hagen von Eitzen's caveat) to give $(x,y)=(45,3),(46,10),$ $(50,22),(54,30),(65,47),$ $(71,55),(79,65),(90,78),$ $(130,122),(171,165),$ $(254,250),(505,503)$.

For $n=3$ we need $(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=2016$. Since $x^2+xy+y^2>x^2-2xy+y^2>(x-y)^2$ and $12^3<2016<13^3$ we need $(x-y)\le12$ and $x^2+xy+y^2\ge168$. That gives the only possibilities for $(x-y,x^2+xy+y^2)$ as $(12,168),(9,224),(8,252),$ $(7,288),(6,336),$ $(4,504),(3,672),(2,1008)$. But if $x=y\bmod 3$, then $x^2+xy+y^2=0\bmod 3$, which rules out the first two. Some similar arguments and some brute force establish there are no solutions for $n=3$.

For any solution for $n=4$ must correspond to a solution $(x^2,y^2)$ for $n=2$ and there are no such solutions in the list. Similarly we can rule out $n=6,8,9,10$.

For $n=5$ we have $x^5-y^5=(x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)$, so $x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4$ must be a factor of $2016$. Since $7^4>2016$, there are only a small number of candidates for $(x,y)$ that do not make $x^4+\dots$ too big, and it is easy to check that there are no solutions for $n=5$. Similarly for $n=7$.

For $n>10$ the difference between two successive positive $n$th powers is at least $2^{11}-1^{11}=2047$, so there are no solutions for $n>10$.

Comment: As certainly $x\equiv y\pmod 2$, we can replace $n>10$ with $n>6$ as $3^7-1^7>2016$.